# How can I use cyrillic text in typescript with react? I get only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cyrillic

I use typescript and have code like this in template:

```html
<div >Текст на русском</div>
```

As a result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAbKv.png)

Could you please help me? How can I get normal view in browser?

Comment: did you check wether your .ts files are UTF8 encoded, and served as such? And does your font support cyrillic characters?

Comment: Can you check if character encoding is UTF-8 in head section of your page, also your ts files are UTF-8 encoded